# UIPageViewController, I can page forward but I can not page backward

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, interface-builder, uipageviewcontroller

I learn how to use `UIPageViewController` here http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPageViewController_Application and I make the example run.  But when I put it into my app I just replace the text to be turn with image, and I find that the images can be paged forward but not backward,  I really exam the code carefully but I can not find out the reason? Is anyone who meet this problem?

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:(BigPictureViewController *)viewController];
    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound))
    {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:(BigPictureViewController *)viewController];

    if (index == NSNotFound)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    if (index == [self.pageContent count])
    {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `UISplitViewController`, remove it's swipe gesture with `splitViewController.presentWithGesture = NO`

Answer (score 0):

you may have not connected the xib event to the relevent method.

Comment: if I do not connected the xib, I can not page forward too. But I can page forward.

Comment: i mean put here in the question

Comment: Try an NSLog to print out the viewcontroller you're returning.  That will let you test whether your VCBeforeVC is being called, whether your index is correct, etc.

Comment: It is called and the index is really decrease, but the page don`t move

Comment: I put the UIPageViewController in a UINavigationViewController stack

Comment: Is the VC you're returning correct? Are you using ARC, or have you tried running with Zombies on to see if you're overreleasing anything?